# How to record terminal execute log?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to record bash execute history in a log, including input and output, and timestamp.
The command `history` only can record input, but not output and timestamp.
What can I do to archive this?

Comment: Not easy (not that I heard of, actually). A compromise is to record everything as printed on screen, which is usually done on the terminal emulator level. You don't have timestamps that way, but you can include timestamps in your prompt to guide you, which is what I do.

Comment: By the way, Zsh's history at least has the advantage of including timestamps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print execution time of a shell command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656425/print-execution-time-of-a-shell-command)

Comment: @ZsoltBotykai I think it's two problems, I don't want execute-time, i want a timestamp, it just like '2015-11-03 17:53:29'

Comment: Somebody might flood the log by constantly typing `cat output.log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the proper time-stamp you could use the infamous `script` command, which allows the recording of a terminal session to a file. Now you can use its' `-t` parameter to record the time between two commands (but this will be recorded to `STDERR` (read the fine manual). Then you have the option to (altogether with `script`) to either set your `$PS1` to include a time-stamp (or `$PROMPT_COMMAND`), so that was that is also included in `script`'s output.