# How to execute a code n times from the terminal?

Tags: java, terminal

I run an example using the following command.

```
java -cp bin examples.generators.SimpleCircuitGenerator
```

This code outputs the time of running the SimpleCircuitGenerator. I wonder how to run the same code multiple times. How can I do it using the terminal? My goal is to measure the time of running the SimpleCircuitGenerator multiple times.

Comment: that is not really [java] specific more like operational system stuff, or do you want to program that in java?

Comment: Yes. I want it in java

Comment: If you want a program to do it, then you'll need to write a program. Otherwise, it is a bit O/S dependent. On Linux (or Windows using Cygwin), I'd use a `for` loop and `seq`.

Comment: then you are not going to run `java -cp ... ` multiple times. To repeat a code use `for` loop, to register its time use `System.nanoTime()` or better, use some framework like JMH (not sure how that is `from the terminal`)

Comment: Write a loop in Java and use java processbuilder.

Comment: One could write [Java Single-Source program](https://dzone.com/articles/launch-single-file-source-code-programs-in-jdk-11) I suppose...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bash shell script for 100 iteration and log time taken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723818/bash-shell-script-for-100-iteration-and-log-time-taken)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can repeat terminal commands as mentioned in the following link.

http://www.mactricksandtips.com/2012/02/loop-repeat-terminal-commands.html

But I suggest you add a for loop and get the number of repetitions as an argument. So you can run the command the number of times you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by using a `for` loop in bash : https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bsd-appleosx-linux-bash-shell-run-command-n-times/

Answer (score 1):

```
FOR %A IN (1 2 3 4 5) DO java -cp bin examples.generators.SimpleCircuitGenerator
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `bash` loop for something like this:
`for i in {1..10}; do java -cp bin examples.generators.SimpleCircuitGenerator; done`.
This may have more information for you: [How to run a command multiple times, using bash shell?](https://serverfault.com/questions/273238/how-to-run-a-command-multiple-times-using-bash-shell)

Answer (score 0):

I think the fastest solution is for you to run it throug a script. I'm assumming you use a Linux based terminal. Open a file and type:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Basic until loop
counter=1
until [ $counter -gt 10 ]
do
java -cp bin examples.generators.SimpleCircuitGenerator
((counter++))
done
```

In this case, it would run up to 10 times. You can modify it as you wish. Save the file as name_of_file.sh and run it.

Comment: Soooo complicated; what's wrong with `for i in $(seq 1 10)`?

Answer (score 0):

Create a bash file example.sh, put the following lines in it and run it ./example.sh . It will run 10 times and print time for each run. Also check out [Print execution time of a shell command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656425/print-execution-time-of-a-shell-command)

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in {1..10}
do
    java -cp bin examples.generators.SimpleCircuitGenerator 
done
```